# call function to check if input is divisible by 7

Tags: python, function

A programme that check if the user input number is divisible by 7. No error until I run and enter the number, then I receive a number of errors. where is the mistake, please?

```
def inputdata():
    userinput=float(input("Enter number:"))
    return userinput

def processdata (userinput):

    reminder=userinput % 7
    if reminder==0:
        result=True
        return result

    else:
        result=False
        return result

def outputdata(result):
    if result==True:
        answer=(print("It is dividable by 7"))
        return answer
    if result==False:
        answer=(print("It is not dividable by 7"))
        return answer

def main():
    inputdata()
    processdata(inputdata)
    outputdata(processdata)
```

Comment: Python is sensitive to indentations. Is the code snippet above indented correctly?

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Please respect Python's convention of using 4 spaces indents, that will make your code readable for everyone and avoid such errors.

Comment: Indentation is correct on the Repl..just when I copied it here it got broken. Its not the indentation because otherwise it wouldn't run. On Repl, the code run and take the input but once I press enter it generate the errors

Comment: Also, `answer=(print("It is not dividable by 7"))` will assign to `answer` the return value of `print`, which is `None`. You should either print or return the value - and you should rather return it.

Comment: "Its not the indentation because otherwise it wouldn't run" - well, no, it could well run differently.

Comment: Please add the errors you receive. Also, because you are using `float` it is suggested that you will avoid direct comparisons like `remainder == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the main part.
There were some problems with the main()

```
def inputdata():
    userinput=float(input("Enter number:"))
    return userinput

def processdata (userinput):

    reminder=userinput % 7
    if reminder==0:
        result=True
        return result

    else:
        result=False
        return result

def outputdata(result):
    if result==True:
        answer=(print("It is dividable by 7"))
        return answer
    if result==False:
        answer=(print("It is not dividable by 7"))
        return answer

def main(): 
    inp = inputdata() # <---------
    pr_data = processdata(inp) # <-------------
    outputdata(pr_data)
```

---

```
Enter number:21
It is dividable by 7

Enter number:2
It is not dividable by 7
```

**One liner Solution:**

```
g = lambda x:  "It is not dividable by 7" if x%7 else "It is dividable by 7"
g(int(input("Enter Number: ")))
```

---

```
Enter Number: 12
It is not dividable by 7
```

Comment: Yep, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: If the answer helps close the question by clicking on the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def divisible(x):
    return x % 7 == 0

userinput = int(input())
if divisible(userinput):
    print('Case true')
else:
    print('Case false')
```

Note that `answer=(print("It is dividable by 7"))` is not valid in python since `print` returns a `None` value

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are passing parameters correctly in main().  You have:

```
 def main():
  inputdata()
  processdata(inputdata)
  outputdata(processdata)
```

but (crudely) what might work is

```
def main():
  outputdata(processdata(inputdata()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your program is a bit to complicated in terms of the number of functions your using. Also your input wasn't converted into a integer in order to perform the calculation:

```
def trydivision(promt):
   """Test if what is given from the user is divisible by 7"""
   try:
      value = int(promt) % 7
      if value == 0:
         print("Yes, " + str(promt) + " is divisible by 7.")
         print("The result is " + str(value))
      else:
        print("The number " + str(promt) + " is not divisible by 7.")
        
    except ValueError:
      print("Please type an integer and not a string!")

promt = input("Enter Number: ")
trydivision(promt)
```